# Example uses of Judy trees

Tags: data-structures

I was reading about [Judy trees](http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/10minutes.htm). What are some examples of real world usage and comparisons to other data structures?

Comment: Very interesting. There's a bunch of links on the HP site about when to use it and advantages etc http://docs.hp.com/en/B6841-90001/ch01s01.html?jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN

Comment: You'd be lucky! "Judy rarely compromises speed/space performance for simplicity" puts most people off using them.

Comment: Seems like a community wiki question since there is not going to be a right answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Judy arrays in Python: http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyJudy.html

Some [Examples uses](http://judy.sourceforge.net/examples/index.html).

> PyJudy arrays are similar to Python dictionaries and sets. The primary difference is that PyJudy keys are sorted; by unsigned value if an integer, byte ordering if a string and object id if a Python object. In addition to wrapping the underlying Judy functions, PyJudy implements a subset of the Python dictionary interface for the JudyL and JudySL API and a subset of the set interface for the Judy1 API, along with some extensions for iterating a subrange of the sorted keys, values and items.